# How to only recognise full options from getopt in a Bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm writing a Bash script to parse command line options and then execute the desired function.

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMP=`getopt --longoptions help --options h --name 'script.sh' -- "$@"`

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
  echo "Try 'script.sh --help' for more information." >&2 ;
  exit 1 ;
fi

eval set -- "$TEMP"

while true ; do
  case "$1" in
    -h|--help)
      echo "Usage:";
      exit 0;;
    --)
      shift ;
      break ;;
    *)
      echo "Internal error!" ;
      exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

echo "Remaining arguments:"
for arg do
  echo '--> '"'$arg'" ;
done
```

`./script.sh --` outputs

> ```
> Remaining arguments:
> ```

All of

- `./script.sh --h`
- `./script.sh --he`
- `./script.sh --hel`
- `./script.sh --help`

output

> ```
> Usage:
> ```

and `./script.sh --helps` outputs

> ```
> script.sh: unrecognized option '--helps'
> Try 'script.sh --help' for more information.
> ```

How do I stop the truncated options from being recognised as the full option? I can't find anything like "end of string" in Bash patterns. Why doesn't `--` get detected as the start of `--help`?

Answer (score 0):

From [man getopt](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt):

> Long  options  may  be abbreviated, as long as the abbreviation is not ambiguous.

So as long as abbreviation is not ambiguous, it will be abbreviated. You could add some other option to make it ambiguous:

```
TEMP=`getopt --longoptions help helpx --options h --name 'script.sh' -- "$@"`
```

Will give you something like:

```
./script.sh    --he
script.sh: option '--he' is ambiguous; possibilities: '--help' '--helpx'
Try 'script.sh --help' for more information.
```

Comment: I think I'll just have to live with it. I'm not a Linux person so I don't always know the expected conventions. I don't want to surprise people.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling options in a more generic way, you should care for those options you are interested in:

```
for i in "$@"; do
    case "$i" in
        -h|--help)
            echo "usage"
            exit 0
            ;;
        --one|--two|--tree)
            continue
            ;;
        *)
            echo "error"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
```